# Loop through a POST array

Tags: php, loops, post

I need to loop through a post array and submit it.

```
#stuff 1
<input type="text" id="stuff" name="stuff[]" />
<input type="text" id="more_stuff" name="more_stuff[]" />
#stuff 2
<input type="text" id="stuff" name="stuff[]" />
<input type="text" id="more_stuff" name="more_stuff[]" />
```

But I don't know where to start.

Comment: Same way you loop through every other array you've come across...

Comment: Some example code would be nice.

Comment: Read some basic documentation, such as http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: This question Needs More Focus.  We don't know your final expectation from "submitting it".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is how you would do it:

```
foreach( $_POST as $stuff ) {
    if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
        foreach( $stuff as $thing ) {
            echo $thing;
        }
    } else {
        echo $stuff;
    }
}
```

This looks after both variables and arrays passed in `$_POST`.

Comment: problem is what about more_stuff[]?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` is much easier. If you really want, you can even throw it between some `<pre>` tags

Comment: nice solution but theres a semicolon missing after the first echo :P

Answer (score 30):

Likely, you'll also need the values of each form element, such as the value selected from a dropdown or checkbox.

```php
 foreach( $_POST as $stuff => $val ) {
     if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
         foreach( $stuff as $thing) {
             echo $thing;
         }
     } else {
         echo $stuff;
         echo $val;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['NAME']); $i++)
{
   echo $_POST['NAME'][$i];
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($_POST['NAME'] as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Replace `NAME` with element name eg `stuff` or `more_stuff`

Comment: $i  < count($_POST['NAME']); would be more correct, no?

Answer (score 3):

I have adapted the accepted answer and converted it into a function that can do nth arrays and to include the keys of the array.

```
function LoopThrough($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($key))
            LoopThrough($key);
        else 
            echo "{$key} - {$val} <br>";
    }
}

LoopThrough($_POST);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_walk_recursive and anonymous function, eg:

```
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');
array_walk_recursive($fruits,function ($item, $key){
    echo "$key holds $item <br/>\n";
});
```

follows this answer version:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST,function ($item, $key){
    echo "$key holds $item <br/>\n";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I lost my index names using the posted answers. Therefore I had to loop them like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $i => $stuff) {
  var_dump($i);
  var_dump($stuff);
  echo "<br>";
}
```